# Bad String in json response using Post man

Tags: java, json, spring

I am Returning string as shown below from a method on service call, when i call this service in Postman it returns **Bad String** .

```
@Override
public synchronized String doDevicePair() throws SomeException    
{
    String returnString = null;     
      /*some logic over here*/

             returnString = "{\"success\": true,   \"payload\": \"success!\", "
            + "{\"userIdA\":\""+user1.getUserId()+"\", \"userIdB\":\""+user2.getUserId()+"\", \"tagName\":\""+tagName+"\" }"+"}";

     return returnString;
      }
```

I think its giving Bad String response because of Wrong syntax of return String.
so i tried

```
returnString = "{\"success\": true,   \"payload\": \"success!\", "
            + "{\"userIdA\":\""+user1.getUserId()+"\", \"userIdB\":\""+user2.getUserId()+"\", \"tagName\":\""+tagName+"\" }}";
```

//gives bad string reponse

so i just checked by returning hardcoded string

```
returnString = "{\"success\": true,   \"payload\": \"succes\"  }";
```

This produces json response on service call , without any error

Whats going wrong? Please help me on this

Comment: You should use a proper JSON library and you can build HashMap's into JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the string name for the inner object. Perhaps it should be:

```
returnString = 
    "{\"success\": true,   \"payload\": \"success!\", \"foo\": " // <-- missing property name
        + "{\"userIdA\":\"" + user1.getUserId()
        + "\", \"userIdB\":\"" + user2.getUserId()
        + "\", \"tagName\":\"" + tagName + "\" }"
    + "}";
```

Comment: I need to append to existing object itself. No need to create inner object.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you use JSON object, good to check the formatting first on some sites. There are bunch of good sites for that like here. [JSON ONLINE EDITOR](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/). Also, you would better to use for the JSON string by using JSON library like JSON Simple.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error in post but it resolved now. you can run one method where you get the response in json and then that same response you can you for post body data.